# Installing a ceiling fan with remote

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a white, black, red and bare cooper wires coming from ceiling. The fan I bought has a remote and the remote sensor is already installed/attached to the mounting hardware.

The remote sensor has a white wire and a red wire coming out of it and a bundled wire that is blue, black and white and has a cap to plug into the same bundling on the motor; the motor also has a green wire grounded to it.

Any idea which words to connect to the ceiling from my electrical box? I attached the white to white and black from ceiling to red in remote sensor and nothing worked.

I took a picture as well and will try to post.

Comment: What do the installation instructions say? How was the old fixture installed?

Comment: The instructions just say red from receiver to black supply and white to white. Old one had blue to black supply, the blue now is bundled with two other wires. Completely different.

Comment: When you had it connected it up as described, did you toggle the pull switch on the fan (if applicable) to make sure it wasn't off?  Did you toggle the wall switch? Did you toggle the remote?

Comment: With the old fixture, was it black from the ceiling to blue on the fixture, and red  from the ceiling to black on the fixture?

Answer (score 2):

If this is correctly wired, using the US color conventions, and the old fan had separate wall-switches for the fan and its lights:

- Black: Hot (probably switched hot, power for either fan or light)
- Red: "Alternate Hot" (probably switched power for either light or fan -- whichever wasn't supplied by black)
- White: Neutral.
- Green or bare copper: Safety ground.

Check that with a meter or test light, though!

If you're adding a remote-control receiver, see its instructions for how it connects between power and the fan.